# import package which is installed in development mode

Tags: python

I've cloned a github repository in the same directory as my project. Then I installed the module using `python3.6 setup.py develop`, because I need to debug the library.

Let's say the package is called `bar`. When I am trying to import the package with `import bar` it still uses the already installed package and not the development version.

How can I specifically import the development package?

Comment: you probably have it installed, do `pip freeze | grep bar` and post what that outputs

Comment: it shows the package `keras-rl==0.4.2`. Do I need to uninstall the package?

Comment: yes you have it installed do `pip uninstall keras-rl==0.4.2` and then try again to set up the package in development mode. if you do the `pip freeze` command after that you should see the package prefixed with a `-e`